# Hit Test in UIView in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a UIViewController I am adding a UIView named testView

```
@property(nonatomic) UIView * testView;

-(UIView *)testView{
    if (!_testView) {
        _testView = [UIView new];

        _puzzleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  }
return testView

}
```

then I add that View to ViewController. I want to detect the touch in testView. How can I add the hitTest method in that UIView which is in a ViewController

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060365/hittestwithevent-and-subviews

Comment: Simplest way is to put a `UITapGestureRecognizer` or any other `UIGestureRecognizer` and install it on the view you want. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In ViewController add follow code :**

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    point = [self.testView.layer convertPoint:point fromLayer:self.layer]; 
    if ([self.testView.layer containsPoint:point]) {
        //touch on the testView
    }
 }
```